# .net core MVC tries validate IEnumerable options for dropdown, but Required attr is only "expression"

Tags: c#, validation, model-view-controller, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an issue with model validation in webapp (.NET core MVC) - in form there are few dropdown lists, these DDLs have as expression required non-nullable int parameter and SelectListItem option list. I am getting message the SelectListItem option lists are required (the int parameter pass as valid). What is wrong or what I missed?

Model (MyModel f.e.):

```csharp
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = nameof(MyResources.Day), ResourceType = typeof(MyResources))]
    public int Day { get; set; }
    
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Days { get; set; }
```

Controller, GET method

```csharp
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Index() {
        var model = MyModel();
        FillModelOptions(model);
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Index(MyModel model) {
        if (ModelState.IsValid) {
            *save form, go somewhere*
        }
        FillModelOptions(model);
        return View(model);
    }

    private void FillModelOptions(MyModel model) {
        var days = new List<SelectListItem>();
        for (var i = 1; i < 32; i++) {
            days.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = i.ToString(), Value = i.ToString() });
        }
        
        model.Days = days.AsEnumerable();
    }
```

In view I have `@Html.ValidationSummary(false, "")` and this returns me hidden error: **`The Days field is required.`** (but the Days is IEnumerable, and Day is not empty)

View:

```html
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "MyController", FormMethod.Post) {
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(false, "") @*after post getting The Days field is required*@
        
        <div class="somebootstrapclasses">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Day, Model.Days, "Select...", new {@class="form-select", @aria_label="Select..."})
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Day)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Day)
        </div>
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write the property like this in MyModel :

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Days { get; set; }
```

[image]

The `Days` property is non-nullable(Equivalent to hermit adding a [Required] property) by default, So if you don't bind any value to this property, `ModelState.IsValid` will return false.

If you don't want this, you can disable this by deleting the below line from the csproj file or setting it as disable. By default(.Net 6) value is enable.

```
<Nullable>enable</Nullable>
```

**Or**, you can just add `?` to make it nullable:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem>? Days { get; set; }
```

**Or**, make `ModelState` ignore this property:

```
if (ModelState.Remove("Days"))
{
      *save form, go somewhere*
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Just question, in .NET framework (4.x) projects I use this lists too, but there is not needed to set them as nullable, also there is no settings in csproj. Is this something typical for .NET core (or .NET 6) ? I see this for the first time.

Comment: It is a new feature in `.Net 6`. In previous version(.Net 5,.Net 3.1...), It is disabled by default. If this answer solve your issue, Can you accept it as the asnwer? Thank you so much.